# How to fix int not working error?

Tags: c++

[NOTE: the code might be in not exactly c :) still need help plsssss]

So I have this code and I am trying to play tic tac toe but one of the int is not working, int x is supposed to be the number of rounds that have passed but since the beginning of the game (when it is set to be 0) it automatically changes to 1 even though it has not yet been activated.

```
    int a1 = 0;
int a2 = 0;
int a3 = 0;
int b1 = 0;
int b2 = 0;
int b3 = 0;
int c1 = 0;
int c2 = 0;
int c3 = 0;

int x = 0;

while(true)
{
```

The following code is repeated exactly the same for all of the other board square

```
if (c1 < 1)
 {
  if((SensorUS(IN_1)<LONG)&&(SensorUS(IN_1)>FAR))
  {
   BTCheck1(B1);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   RemoteResetMotorPosition(B1,OUT_C,true);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   MOTOR1(OUT_C,100);
   c1 = 2;
   x = x + 1;
   Wait(1000);
  }
 }
```

Then this is what the computer is supposed to do but it is just ignoring that and it is playing as if x = every value

```
    if (x = 1)
 {
  if (a1 = 0)
  {
   BTCheck1(B1);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   RemoteResetMotorPosition(B1,OUT_A,true);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   MOTOR1(OUT_A,100);
   a1 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
  else if (b1 = 0)
  {
   BTCheck1(B1);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   RemoteResetMotorPosition(B1,OUT_B,true);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   MOTOR1(OUT_B,100);
   b1 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
  else if (c2 = 0)
  {
   BTCheck2(B2);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B2)==NO_ERR);
   RemoteResetMotorPosition(B2,OUT_C,true);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B2)==NO_ERR);
   MOTOR2(OUT_C,100);
   c2 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
  else if (a3 = 0)
  {
   OnFwd(OUT_A,100);
   a3 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
  else if (c3 = 0)
  {
   OnFwd(OUT_C,100);
   c3 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
  else if (a2 = 0)
  {
   BTCheck2(B2);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B2)==NO_ERR);
   RemoteResetMotorPosition(B2,OUT_A,true);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B2)==NO_ERR);
   MOTOR2(OUT_A,100);
   a2 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
  else if (c1 = 0)
  {
   BTCheck1(B1);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   RemoteResetMotorPosition(B1,OUT_C,true);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B1)==NO_ERR);
   MOTOR1(OUT_C,100);
   c1 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
  else if (b3 =0)
  {
   BTCheck2(B2);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B2)==NO_ERR);
   RemoteResetMotorPosition(B2,OUT_B,true);
   until(BluetoothStatus(B2)==NO_ERR);
   MOTOR2(OUT_B,100);
   b3 = 1;
   x = x + 1;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Yes, it's work, but it's your only chance to get meaningful answers, because first of all, others must be able to *reproduce* your problem.

Comment: As soon as you find yourself doing stuff like a1, a2, b1, b2, what you really want is an array. And as soon as you use an array, you'll find you can very easily generalize a single function to handle all of the possibilities.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Remove the tag for the unrelated. And read [ask].

Comment: Please turn on / turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: If `x` is supposed to be "the number of rounds that have passed but since the beginning of the game", why on Earth do you call it `x`? At least give it a meaningful name like `rounds`.

Comment: "NOTE: the code might be in not exactly c" - **So use the correct language tag!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the assignment operator `=` where you should be using the equality operator `==`

> if (x = 1)

That is where your x becomes 1

Comment: Indeed, that's incorrect all over the code, therefore a good guess.

Comment: OMG thank you so much I feel so stupid

Comment: Don't, it is part of the learning process. =)  Pay attention to the compiler warnings, most probably they where flagging this problem from the beginning.